# Auto Attach Process in Visual Studio 2015

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

I'm using Visual Studio 2015 to debug a website running on a .NET framework.  When setting break points in one of my .aspx.vb files it gives me an error saying:

"The break point will not be hit.  No symbols have been loaded for this document."

Now I have solved how to fix this error by going to Debug -> Attach to Process then attaching it to the process of my IIS.

The issue is I have to do this every time I stop and restart debug mode.  Is there anyway to get this process to automatically attach when I begin debugging?

Answer (score 0):

The [ReAttach](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/8cccc206-b9de-42ef-8f5a-160ad0f017ae) extension gives you an easy way to ReAttaching your prior debug targets.